# What will be the correct documents design

Tags: ravendb

First of all a warning: I'm totally new to Document databases so all of my "understanding" comes from documentation and blog posts and this is my first hands-on work.

I want to achieve the following:

1. Store different type of documents and manage some metadata around the documents.
2. Query the database by:

   - metadata
   - metadata and document attributes
   - metadata for a particular document type
3. Update the metadata without having to load the whole document.

My understanding is that I have two options here.

Have metadata saved together with the document.

```
public class Metadata
{
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set;}
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set;}
}

public class DocumentWithMetadata<T>
{
    public T Document { get; set;}
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set;}
}
```

Have an index that will include the metadata attributes and Use `LiveProjections` to load metadata of a document without loading the whole document. For updates of on the metadata use PATCH. According to the documentation `..."is considered to be an expert feature and generally should not be used as a general purpose solution. If you have reached a scenario where you are considering using this, you might want to recheck your data model and see if it can be optimized to prevent usage of the Patching API"`

The other option is to save the metadata as a standalone document.

```
public class Metadata
{
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set;}
    public DateTime? ValidTo { get; set;}
}

public class DocumentWithMetadata<T>
{
    public T Document { get; set;}
    public string MetadataId { get; set;}
}
```

In this approach I can use the `Related Document Indexing` feature and "lift" the metadata attributes into the document's index.

Given that for document of type `T1` Raven will create a collection called `DocumentWithMetadataOfT1`, how would I query **only** for metadata of T1 documents if all the metadata is in one collection?

I thought about a couple other approaches like add document type property to the metadata or invert the relations but all of them seem like hacks.

There must be a better way.. or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very confusing what you are actually trying to do.  Mainly because Raven already has it's own concepts of a document and metadata and you are introducing your own for some reason.

Based on the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` fields you are adding to the metadata, my guess is that you are attempting some sort of bi-temporal effectivity or "history table".  This is actually done already, so if that's what you are after then you should just use my [Temporal Versioning Bundle](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-TemporalVersioning/wiki).

Comment: Thanks Matt, as I mentioned I'm a total beginner with RavenDB and Document databases in general, so there is a lot to learn. As a learning project I wanted to implement [Slowly Changing Dimension of type 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension). I will look at the Temporal Versioning Bundle tonight.

Can the Temporal Versioning Bundle be extended with custom “tracking fields”? for example used id who made the change?

Comment: This is a bit of an advanced concept.  My advise is to start with just plain RavenDB and get acclimated to document database patterns first.  Once you are no longer thinking in the relational database mindset, then look at Temporal Versioning and it will make much more sense to you.  Yes, you can extend it, but you don't need to do anything special.  Just simply store additional data or metadata fields and they will be versioned appropriately.  Regarding SCD Type 2 - yes, this is a similar concept, but that's more of a OLAP terminology.

Comment: We are dealing with daily dumps of data. Those files a snapshots of all the data in other systems. The files contain up to ~300K records where the the change rate is very small, in worst case around 1% - 1.5%. I want to capture only the changed documents (rows in a dump file) using a checksum to detect changes. The reason that I'm looking into document databases is that I don't have to deal with database schemas for each of the ~20 dumps that we need to work with.

Comment: It sounds like you're building a data warehouse.  This is possible, but it's not Raven's primary focus.  Again, learn the basics before you try to do something advanced.  Raven's `DocumentSession` can tell if something is modified or not, but you will need to batch your data into smaller chunks.  Bulk Import is available, but isn't going to do the kind of diff comparison you are looking for.